# Problema al mostar datos en input

Tags: php, sql

Estoy teniendo problemas a la hora de que me muestre los datos bien en los imput.
Tengo dos opciones una de agregar y otra de editar, en agregar datos no hay problema, pero a la hora de editar, en el imput me printa los datos pero no todo, es decir, por ejemplo, si yo tengo un input con varias palabras por ejemplo los apellidos, solo me aparece el primer apellido, no me aparece si tiene un espacio y luego otra palabra. El problema es que si lo dejo asi al dar al botón editar, se guarda solo con los primeros datos y si esos datos tienen mas texto, desaparece.No se si me explico bien.... Esto es tema de la base de datos?

```
if($_GET){

    $id= $_GET['id'];
    $sql_unico = 'SELECT * FROM reportes WHERE id=?';

$gsnet_unico = $pdo->prepare($sql_unico);
$gsnet_unico->execute(array($id));

$resultado_unico = $gsnet_unico->fetch();
}

<?php if($_GET):?>
    <h2>Editar elementos</h2>
<form method="GET" action="editar_reportes.php">
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre" value=<?php echo $resultado_unico['nombre']?>>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Apellidos" name="apellidos" value=<?php echo $resultado_unico['apellidos']?>>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Categoría" name="categoria" value=<?php echo $resultado_unico['categoria']?>>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Versión" name="version" value=<?php echo $resultado_unico['version']?>>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comisario 1" name="comisario1" value=<?php echo $resultado_unico['comisario1']?>>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comisario 2" name="comisario2" value=<?php echo $resultado_unico['comisario2']?>>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comisario 3" name="comisario3" value=<?php echo $resultado_unico['comisario3']?>>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comisario 4" name="comisario4" value=<?php echo $resultado_unico['comisario4']?>>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Comisario 5" name="comisario5" value=<?php echo $resultado_unico['comisario5']?>>
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Sanción" name="sancion" value=<?php echo $resultado_unico['sancion']?>>
<input type="hidden" name="id" value=<?php echo $resultado_unico['id']?> >
<button class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Editar</button>
</form>
<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero, podría ser tema de la consulta SQL que trae tus datos, verificala.
Segundo, puede ser que tu Input esté con max-length y eso no te permita agregar un valor mas largo, verifica la etiqueta Input donde vuelcas el valor.

Si pudieras poner tu query SQL y tu codigo donde lo envias al input podría ayudarte mas.

Saludos.

Comment: Lo he editado para que puedas ver el código

Comment: Puedes intentar poner comillas en value?

`<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nombre" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $resultado_unico['nombre']?>">
`
Estas usando algo aparte de PHP?, algún framework?

Comment: Estoy usando bootstrap y material desing bootstrap

Comment: Se ha solucionado con las comillas

Comment: Que bien, suerte en tu desarrollo!

Comment: Muchas gracias Mauricio!